# Using two conditionals in an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to use two conditional statements for one task in an Ansible playbook, but only one of the conditions is being honored.  If they are used individually they both work, but not together.  Task snippet is below.

```
    - name: close change request
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['localhost'] and "'{{ chgtyp }}' in 'n''N'"
      include_role:
        name: chgclose
```

Has anyone ran into this problem or know how to solve it?
Ansible version 2.9.18

Comment: You have multiple issues: when should never be templated, you list seems quite odd, ...

Comment: But basically I guess you are looking for  `when: "'localhost' in group_names and chgtyp in ['n', 'N']"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the variable

```yaml
    chgtyp: n
```

and the inventory below for testing

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[localhost]
srv1

[localhost2]
srv2
```

Let's test the conditions separately. First, test the value of *chgtyp*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: OK. close change request
      when: chgtyp|lower == 'n'
```

gives for both 'n' and 'N'

```yaml
ok: [srv1] => 
  msg: OK. close change request
```

Next test the group

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: OK. close change request
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.localhost
```

gives the same result for a play running on 'srv1'

```yaml
ok: [srv1] => 
  msg: OK. close change request
```

Now, put the conditions together and test both positive and negative results

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: close change request
      when:
        - inventory_hostname in groups.localhost
        - chgtyp|lower == 'n'
```

**Notes**

- See [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals)
- When you have multiple conditions that all need to be true (that is, a logical and), you can specify them as a list
- You do not need to use {{ }} on variables inside conditionals, as these are implicitly implied.